# Python using RE to find integer in text file in a for

Tags: regex, python-2.7, tweepy

I'm writing a bot in python using tweepy for python 2.7. I'm stumped on how to approach what I am looking to do. Currently the bot finds the tweet id and appends it to a text file. On later runs I want to use regex to search that file for a match and only write if there is no match within the text file. The intent is not to add duplicate tweet ids to my text file which could span a large amount of numbers followed by newline.

Any help is appreciate!

/edit when I try the below code the IDE says match can't be seen and syntax error as a result.

```
import re,codecs,tweepy
qName = Queue.txt
tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery,count=tweet_count,result_type="recent")
with codecs.open(qName,'a',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for tweet in tweets:
        tweetId = tweet.id_str
        match = re.findall(tweedId), qName)
        #if match = false then do write, else discard and move on
        f.write(tweetId + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get you correct,You need not to bother with regex etc. let the special containers do the work for you.I would proceed with non-duplicate-container like `dictionary` or `set` e.g read all the data from file into `dictionary` or `set` and then go for extending id into this `dictionary` or `set` after all write this `dictionary` or `set` back into file.

e.g.

```
>>>data = set()
>>>for i in list('asddddddddddddfgggggg'):
    data.add(i)

>>>data
>>>set(['a', 's', 'd', 'g', 'f']) ## see one d and g
```